# How to create canonical links using zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, canonical-link

I am new in using the zend framework. I have searched but didn't get a solution on how to create canonical links using zend framework 1.

The `rel` attribute of the `link` element should have `canonical`, `next` and `previous` depending on the page you are on.

E.g When on this page (www[dot]example.co.uk/index/testimonials/), the link should be:

> `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.co.uk/index/testimonials/”/>`
>   `<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.co.uk/index/testimonials/page/2”/>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done it a different way in my view/script file;

```
        $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => 'http://www.example.com/index/news?page=1'));
        if ($this->page < count($this->newsList)){
            $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'next', 'href' => 'http://www.example.comk/index/news?page='.($this->page + 1)));
        }
        if ($this->page > 1) {
            $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'prev', 'href' => 'http://www.www.example.com/index/news?page='.($this->page - 1)));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to generate a canonical URL (having the scheme and host name),
you can specify the third parameter for the `Url` view helper. The third parameter
should be an array containing one or several options. For assembling the absolute
URL, pass the `force_canonical` option, as in the example below:

```
<!-- A hyperlink to Home page -->
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('home', array(), 
  array('force_canonical' => true)); ?>" > Home page </a>

<!-- A hyperlink to About page -->
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('application/default', array(
  'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'about'),
  array('force_canonical' => true)); ?>" > About page </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I'm using it with testimonial page pagination.